# How to send special characters to php server

Tags: php, angular, post, character

I am traying to send special characters to a php server. I tried with angular and with jquery getting the same result:

myClient.js with JQuery:

```
data = "Ñoñón";
dataToSend={special_word: data};
$.ajax({    
  type : 'POST',
  url  : 'myServer.php',
  data : dataToSend,
  success :  function(response){
    console.log(response);
 }
});
```

myServer.php for JQuery client:

```
$special_word =mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST["special_word"]));
saveWordInDB($special_word);
echo $special_word;
```

myClient.js with angular:

```
data = "Ñoñón";
dataToSend={special_word: data};
$http.post('myServer.php', dataToSend)
.then(
   function(response){
     // success callback
     console.log(response.data);
   }, 
   function(response){
     // failure callback
     console.log(response);
   }
);
```

myServer.php for angular client

```
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postdata);
$special_word = $request->special_word;
saveWordInDB($special_word);
echo $special_word;
```

In both cases, the word "Ñoñón" is not stored in the DB, but the word "Ã±oÃ±Ã³n" its stored instead. The same occurs with the word showed in the console. How can this be fixed?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you set the encoding of your DB connection to UTF8? Is your database set to utf8? Does `$postdata` have the correct value, does `$request`, does `saveWordInDB` return it correctly? Where do you run the insert?

Comment: Yes to all. In fact, I have more special characters saved in the DB. When I send a special character directly from a <form action='myServer.php>  tag i can retrieve the special characters without problems. But when javascript has to send the special character I don't know how tow send them.

Comment: If `$postdata` outputs as the correct character than the JS sounds like it was implemented correctly, no?

Comment: That's it. I'm pretty sure it's not an implementation error :S

Comment: If `$postdata` gets it than it is a PHP issue. If not than it is an issue with transmitting the request. You need to narrow down where the issue is. Use the developer console, and the PHP error log with `error_log` to see where the value is lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're having utf8_decode issue here, try to decode it before saving in DB

```
$special_word 
=mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, 
$_POST["special_word"]));
saveWordInDB(utf8_decode($special_word));
echo $special_word;
```

*Ref.* http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php